# Error : The key 'SecurityKey' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When I execute my app (Winform)from the computer where it was developed there is no error, but When I execute this in another computer I get the error. My App.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SecurityKey"/>
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"sku="...."/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

and this is the line that I use:

```
string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
```

I already tried to follow this [The key 'UserID' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427007/the-key-userid-does-not-exist-in-the-appsettings-configuration-section), but it is still the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And the error happens with the call to GetValue?

Comment: And what type is settingsReader?

Comment: It will probably not solve your problem, but I prefer using ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["SecurityKey"] to read appSettings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the appSettings in the .config file is different from .settings file.

Take a look at [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx).

I'd also mention that I have no idea how either the settingsReader nor the ConfigurationManager work with a key with no value:

```
<add key="SecurityKey"/> <!-- no value? -->
<add key="SecurityKeyWithValue" value="myvalue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SecurityKey" value="Syed Moshiur Murshed"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hope it helps you

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.